# Arabic character encoding

Tags: character-encoding, translation, right-to-left

I'm using i18next translation library and everything is translated correctly except the Qatari Riyal currency symbol, on IE 11 and FF 30 Win 7. I only see this happening on some browsers so I'm wondering if this has something to do with browser settings - the browsers in question are setup for chinese. My browser language preferences are setup for English US and I'm unable to reproduce this, even after changing the language to Chinese. The currency symbol should render as: ﷼ but is incorrectly rendering as ï-1/4. The file encoding is set to UTF-8, any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the [RIAL SIGN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fdfc/index.htm) U+FDFC “﷼” appears as UTF-8 encoded (bytes 0xEF 0xB7 0xBC) and the data is misinterpreted as iso-8859-1 or windows-1252 encoded, you see U+00EF U+00B7 U+00BC “ï·¼”, and I think this is what you are seeing. So something indeed went wrong with the encoding.

It is impossible to analyze the problem further without more information about the situation. But this *can* happen when the character encoding of a page is not declared at all or it has been wrongly declared. It is also possible that the character was incorrectly code-converted: it appeared as UTF-8 encoded, but for some reason some software processed it as if needed conversion from iso-8859-1 and converted the three bytes of the UTF-8 representation as if they were iso-8859-1 data.

Comment: Yep. I Changed the encoding to iso-8859-1 and it displayed incorrectly. What if I add the encoding to the ajax request content-Type?